# OData server API and expression syntax, literals, and members

Tags: java, mongodb, parsing, odata

I wish to translate an OData query into a MongoDB query.  I have the `olingo-odata4` code and have isolated the calls necessary to take an input string e.g.

```
Name eq 'Buzz' and (amount gt 1.99 or size lt 10)
```

and run it through `ExpressionParser` with my own `ExpressionVisitor` implementation to intercept the various parse states like `visitLiteral` and `visitBinaryOperator`, etc.   From there it is trivial to construct the equivalent MongoDB query.  My `main` is essentially a trimmed down copy of the odata test drivers, including the mocking of the `Edm` class for startup:

```
ExpressionParser ep = new ExpressionParser(mock(Edm.class), odata);
```

My challenge is that I cannot seem to set up the environment properly for the parser to recognize fields, e.g. members.   I would have hoped that `Name eq 'Buzz'` would cause the `visitMember` method to be called for `Name` but it does not; instead, I get a parse fail with the message: `Property paths must follow a structured type`.

So my overall question becomes:   If the `$filter` argument to OData shows the expression syntax as `Name eq 'Buzz'` then what has to happen in the server implementation to recognize `Name` as a member?

Answer (score 2):

The parser is unfortunately too closely coupled to the data model, IMHO.   The test drivers I looked at were mostly `{5 eq 5}` and things like that so I was led astray.  The property path test driver, however, cannot mock the EDM; it must construct a model in order to declare the type (string, etc.) of the fields.   This is why `visitMember` `Member` class has the `getType()` method.   But this means you cannot use the parser to just crack the syntax and dynamically perform actions on the results.

I ended up just creating a very small grammar in ANTLR to parse the OData query expressions and it was easy to convert to MongoDB query language.